# JPA MetaDataException for different datasources

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, openjpa, metamodel

I have the problem with JPA Criteria API while using in my project different datasource persistance.

There are two PU uses different datasources:

```
<persistence-unit name="analysis" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>AnalysisDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>entity1</class>
    <class>entity2</class>
    <class>entity3</class>
```

and

```
<persistence-unit name="reaction" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>ReactionDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>someEntity1</class>
    <class>someEntity2</class>
    <class>someEntity3</class>
```

Spring load it, in applicationContext

```
<bean id="defaultAnalysysDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
      lazy-init="default">
    <property name="jndiName" value="AnalysisDS"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultReactionDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
      lazy-init="default">
     <property name="jndiName" value="ReactionDS"/>
     <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
     <property name="cache" value="true"/>
     <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In my DAO I can work with this PU with EntityManager, for example for 
ReactionDS I'Am using

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "reaction")
 private EntityManager entityManager;
```

And all work done -  simple query's and JPQL expressions.
But when I want to introduce to my DAO JPA Criteria API
Like this :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
...
```

I have exception after getCriteriaBuilder() method works:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: Errors encountered while resolving metadata.  See nested exceptions for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:675)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:418)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:389)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

...
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: Table "ANALYSIS.ENTITY1" given for "entity1" does not exist.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.createTable(MappingInfo.java:532)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMappingInfo.getTable(ClassMappingInfo.java:317)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMappingInfo.getTable(ClassMappingInfo.java:339)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.FullClassStrategy.map(FullClassStrategy.java:73)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.setStrategy(ClassMapping.java:392)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:55)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:410)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:769)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:658)
    ... 147 more
```

The problem root cause in JPA, because his trying to use a tables from Analys  in Reaction PU and extracts all meta-classes for entities that are located in different datasources, but access to them is doing in one.

But when I granted select on Entity1 to ReactionDS  - all works done. (because I can use Select * from Analysis.Entity1 from reaction)

The question - how to make the metamodel classes to choose working only within the specified DS in EntityManager (in current example - Reaction, not together with Analysis) ?

p.s Database is Oracle, using Weblogic 12.1.3 and OpenJpa2.4.
Metamodel is generated automatically with maven plugin on compile:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <processors>
                    <processor>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6</processor>
                </processors>
                <optionMap>
                    <openjpa.metamodel>true</openjpa.metamodel>
                </optionMap>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused by your Spring Framework datasource declarations.

These beans do not define your datasource, they only provide a way for other Spring components to access the datasources that have been configured in your server. JPA does not use these at all.

Therefore, your problem lies in the datasources that you have defined in your WebLogic server. It looks like you have defined both datasources to reference the same database instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In Weblogic jdbc uses different sources of data, and everything is working correctly, if I do not try to use Criteria API instead JPQL query. Problem in metamodel with CriteriaBuilder and  datasource detection for it

Comment: If that is happening then you have found a bug in OpenJPA and should report it as described in [Found a bug?](http://openjpa.apache.org/found-a-bug.html).